# JAX-WS RI generates WSDL on runtime with public URL in schemaLocation attribute of import by default

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

While using JAX-WS RI for publishing SOAP endpoints implemented using generated stubs from predetermined `.wsdl` and `.xsd` files, it automatically generates corresponding WSDL files for the published endpoint. For example an endpoint published at `http://localhost:8081/ep` has its WSDL file at `http://localhost:8081/ep?wsdl` with it containing imports of other schema files which in turn can import more files.

Issue is that one such import in an `.xsd` file is automatically generated with a reference to public URL as such:

```
...
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" 
           schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2006/03/addressing/ws-addr.xsd"/>
...
```

This can be an issue when trying to parse this endpoint's WSDL in an environment with no public internet connectivity. Generated stubs include classes from `ws-addr.xsd`, so JAX-WS RI should be able to generate and publish the `.xsd` from those stubs.

How could this be forced to generate the required `.xsd` schema itself as it does for other namespace schemas and why does this use a public location in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that some other dependency overwrites the default setting for the schema. As the project uses JAX-WS RI, it also includes a dependency for `jakarta.xml.ws-api` which includes a `package-info.java` file in `javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing` package containing the following titbit:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace=W3CEndpointReference.NS,
                                     location="http://www.w3.org/2006/03/addressing/ws-addr.xsd")
package javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing;
```

where `W3CEndpointReference.NS` is `http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing`.

This, through some automatic configuration magic, tells JAX-WS RI to use the given public location when referencing the specified namespace. The default value for location is `##generate` which makes the schema generator generate the required components.

So in order to override this, we can add our own `package-info.java` file into our own codebase but **in the same package**, with the same annotation but with the default value for the location:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace=W3CEndpointReference.NS)
package javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing;
```

(no `location` key means default value is used)

And result is that the generated schema uses a generated addressing `.xsd` file instead of a public one:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
           schemaLocation="http://localhost:8081/ep?xsd=10"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a cleaner solution with `META-INF/jax-ws-catalog.xml`. Here you can configure where CXF should fetch the resources, see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv_adv/xml.html

Example:

```xml
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">
    <system systemId="http://www.w3.org/2006/03/addressing/ws-addr.xsd" 
            uri="classpath:Schemas/ws-addr.xsd"/>
</catalog>
```

We have to put the `ws-addr.xsd` to `src/main/resources/Schemas`.

Seems like CXF developers do similar things here: [META-INF/jax-ws-catalog.xml in systests](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/main/systests/uncategorized/src/test/resources/META-INF/jax-ws-catalog.xml).

Under the hood, the [OASISCatalogManager](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/catalog/OASISCatalogManager.html) will manage this mapping.